# como cambiar una alert normal a sweetalert2 dentro de una consulta

Tags: sql, login, sweetalert

Holallevo rato con este problema, quiero hacer el cambio de una alerta normal a una sweetalert2 dentro de una consulta, que al momento de dar click en "login" este corrobore si el email esta correcto, y si esta vacio que mande dicha sweetAlert

esta es la alerta normal:

alert("Debes compeltar ambos campos<%=request.getAttribute("")%>")

este es el boton

<a  href="#" onclick="buscar();"class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block ">
LOGIN

Comment: falta mas informacion  https://sweetalert2.github.io/ alli hay mas informacion

Answer (score 0):

en tu html añades las siguientes etiquetas:

```
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.7.31/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js "></script>
<link href=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.7.31/dist/sweetalert2.min.css " rel="stylesheet">
```

y dentro de tu función buscar() reemplazas tu el llamado a tu alert por:

```
Swal.fire(
    'Debes completar ambos campos ...'
)
```

Aquí tienes mas info y mas ejemplos de uso:
https://sweetalert2.github.io/